# CSS - Add a margin between two divs

Tags: css

Is there a way to create an inside space between two divs without adding an additional class to each div and applying a `margin-right` & `margin-left`? I want the children of `.list` to fill the container but have a space between them.

```css
.list {
  display: flex;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid blue
}

div {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div>Item</div>
  <div>Item</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `gap: 10px` on the parent element

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS Pseudo class :first-child to select the first div in div.list adn :last-child to select the last div.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes

```css
.list {
  display: flex;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid blue
}

div {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid
}

.list div:first-child {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.list div:last-child {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div>Item</div>
  <div>Item</div>
</div>
```